# Side Roll "Catenoid" pair

Tags: differential-geometry

Apologies in advance for the very poor quality of images.

Longitudinal stretching a catenoid of revolution results in  well-known isometric helicoidal deformation.

Lateral stretch or spread-out results in ( a relatively less known ) two smaller catenoid-like rolls with a smooth bridge connection.

How is it possible to find a parametrization based on isometry for this two-roll configuration? i.e., we can assume conserved (negative) Gauss curvature K in the deformation process.

Whether mean curvature $H$ also remains zero as a minimal surface is one related matter.

The segment is a $(K<0)$ portion of a thin plastic drinking water container showing three elastic deformation pictures of the same anti-clastic flexible ring.

EDIT1:

Also searched in the book *Bäcklund and Darboux Tranformations*, by Rogers & Schief, Cambridge 2002, to look for relevance to Solitons or Breathers ( in this example there are loops and in Breather there are circumferential cuspidal edges) , but not able to establish any connections.

EDIT2:

The starting roll has two coincident /repeating loops, which can be seen when unrolled; these multiple cyclic loops (mathematically allowable) can be unfolded to separately appearing displaced coils, qualitatively shown below: The phenomenon has been observed in case of isometric deformations of the sphere and the pseudosphere.

[image: EpiTrachoid]

Downvoting a risk especially when no references to this.. nevertheless posting  for love and conviction with differential geometry.

[image]

[image]

[image]